# Read text file at one step

Tags: java

I need to read text file to String. I do :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = br.readLine();
            String everything = line;

            while (line != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                everything += line + "\n";
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But I dont like to read line by line. It should be possible to read whole file to string at one function call. I'm right? By the way, I must use java 1.4.

Comment: You should not use so old java version.

Comment: readAllBytes was introduced in Java 7 im afraid.

Comment: @Jens is totally normal at job being committed with old java versions... maybe 1.4 is too old... but also all questions are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read the whole file data as byte array.

```
File file = new File(yourFileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
fis.read(data);
fis.close();
String strData=new String(data, "UTF-8"); // converting byte array to string
System.out.println(strData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use an external library, you could have a look on  [Apache Commons FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Besides, you definitely should not use such an old java version.